# BlueTooth Low Energy app is not working on My Devices Nexsus 4 and Nexsus Tab 7

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have Downloaded couple of BLE Apps from Google play. I have enabled Both Devices Blue Tooth. Whenever i am scanning Devices but no devices is showing in the list. How does BLE works, please suggest me. I am new to use BLE. Also I have downloaded sample code from Git hub "https://github.com/StevenRudenko/BleSensorTag". This callback method is not called.

```
// Device scan callback.
private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback = new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, int rssi,
            byte[] scanRecord) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.d("TAG", "name : " + device.getName()
                        + "describeContents : " + device.describeContents()
                        + "getBondState : " + device.getBondState()
                        + "getAddress : " + device.getAddress()
                        + "getType : " + device.getType() + "toString: "
                        + device.toString());
                mLeDeviceListAdapter.addDevice(device);
                mLeDeviceListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }
};
```

please suggest me, how BLE works, Any help will we appreciated.

Comment: Which devices are you scanning. Note that the Android implementation of BLE does not make an Android device act as a BLE device, it only allows them to detect BLE devices.  Also you will find that some of the BLE apps in Google play and available as source code are written to detect specific BLE devices. IIRC the Steven Rudenko BleSensorTag application is written specifically to respond to the TI Sensor Tag Reference Platform/Developer Kit and not to any other 'general' BLE devices

Answer (score 0):

Android devices does not support client mode. They only can work as a Master in connection (They must be GATT client too because the most common scenario is an Android device collecting information from sensors/beacons which they are considered as GATT servers).

The problem you are facing right now is that your devices are both listening for advertising packets but really there is nothing generating those packets. You need a sensor/beacon in order to test Bluetooth Low Energy Android capabilities.